# Trying to create a dynamic page template for all my links across a website

Tags: php, html, database, web

Basically I'm trying to create a database sort of website. 
For example:

I have my index.php, say, index.php has a div container with some links, all of them displaying products from a database. I want to create a single layout, a single page basically so that when any of those links is pressed, the information of those links gets generated into the page. That way I don't have to make new pages for every single link.

I don't really know what kind of php is necessary for something like this, but I would appreciate any small example, links, anything of that kind. 
How could I connect a database to it? Do I create variables, php functions?

For example: Do I do:

```
function product_name()
{
    $name = "product_name" ;
    $detail one = "detail one text" ;
    $detail two = "detail two text" ;
    etc. etc.

    echo .$name.$detailone.$detailtwo. ;
}
```

Please help me understand what I need to do, or please link me to where I need to go to find this information, I am not even sure what I would call this exactly, but I would like an efficient way to manage and share large amounts of data over a website.

Comment: yes, that was a previous question I asked, however, I think I reworded it better this time. More specifically, I don't want to be making 1000's of different pages for 1000's of products.

Comment: The answer you got on your earlier question still applies. Loads of tutorials on Google. And this resource: http://www.phptherightway.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one in this world makes page for every single product. On click of any link make a ajax call with the id of the product. Now make a MySQL database containing information corresponding to that id with columns having name "product name", "description", "cost", "comments" and all other details. now your php will query this information in the database and will make a HTML page for the client and send it over. I seriously advise you to check MySQL database and it will be better if for now you use javascript on client side for better debugging and first get the logic and php on server side to query database and handle clients AJAX calls